# Django-Paypal: How do I receive the buyer's billing address?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, django-paypal

I'm using django-paypal's IPN method, and I'd like to get paypal to send me billing/shipping information whenever a customer makes a purchase, and then have this information stored in my database. Is this even possible with django-paypal?

Whenever I successfully make a purchase with the paypal's sandbox environment, I receive transaction information that includes the buyer's name and email and invoice, but not much else. The buyer's address and contact phone are not stored in PayPal IPNs on the django admin site.

I was wondering if anyone familiar with django-paypal has also encountered this problem in the past and found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

PayPal will never send a "billing" address.  That is one of the advantages of paying with PayPal.  It doesn't share your actual billing info with all the different seller you buy from.

If there is a shipping address included on the order then it would be included with the IPN data.  If you aren't seeing address info in the IPN then the payment must not have included a shipping address.